# "newparticlesystem.startlifetime" is obsolete in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a problem with the following unity code .

```
private ParticleSystem instantiate(ParticleSystem prefab, Vector3 position)
{
    ParticleSystem newParticleSystem = Instantiate(
      prefab,
      position,
      Quaternion.identity
    ) as ParticleSystem;

    // Make sure it will be destroyed
    Destroy(
      newParticleSystem.gameObject,
      newParticleSystem.startLifetime
    );

    return newParticleSystem;
}
```

in the line

```
newparticlesystem.startlifetime
```

I get the following error, which I do not understand.

```
"newparticlesystem.startlifetime" is obsolete 
 startlifetime property is deprecated.
```

Comment: You cant use `startLifetime` nomore. All You gonna do is change your  `newParticleSystem.startLifetime`

to `newParticleSystem.main.startLifetime.constantMin` or `newParticleSystem.main.startLifetime.curveMin`

It depends on what start lige time settings Your are using in this Particle System Object